# SuperSquares NxN

Tags: code-golf, array, matrix

Given an integer **N** from 1-9, you must print an **N**x**N** grid of **N**x**N** boxes that print alternating 1s and **N**s, with each box having an alternating starting integer.

**Examples**

```
Input: 1
Output:

1


Input: 2
Output:

12  21
21  12

21  12
12  21


Input: 3
Output:

131  313  131
313  131  313
131  313  131

313  131  313
131  313  131
313  131  313

131  313  131
313  131  313
131  313  131


Input: 4
Output:

1414  4141  1414  4141
4141  1414  4141  1414
1414  4141  1414  4141
4141  1414  4141  1414

4141  1414  4141  1414
1414  4141  1414  4141
4141  1414  4141  1414
1414  4141  1414  4141

1414  4141  1414  4141
4141  1414  4141  1414
1414  4141  1414  4141
4141  1414  4141  1414

4141  1414  4141  1414
1414  4141  1414  4141
4141  1414  4141  1414
1414  4141  1414  4141
```

An array (of NxN arrays) or text in this format is acceptable.

Comment: Can we output an \$N^2 \times N^2\$ matrix? Must there be separators between the blocks?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing > An array of numbers or text in this format is acceptable.

Comment: @Fmbalbuena That doesn't answer the question

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Any data type that expresses separated boxes of numbers in this format acceptable

Comment: @drmosley So is `[[1,2,2,1],[2,1,1,2],[1,2,2,1],[,2,1,1,2]]` an acceptable output for \$N = 2\$?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing `[[[1,2,2,1],[2,1,1,2]],[[1,2,2,1],[,2,1,1,2]]]` would be correct. I should clarify: separated boxes and rows/columns of boxes

Comment: @drmosley `131` (the number) and `'131'` (the string) are both allowed formats for the individual elements.  Is a list of digits `1 3 1` also allowed?

Comment: @Jonah yes, as long as groups of digits are organized into separable blocks in some way

Answer (score 10):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```
#^Array[Plus,#+0{,,,}]~Mod~2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7XznOsagosTI6IKe0WEdZ26BaR0enNrbONz@lzkjtf0BRZl6JQ0h@cAmQkR7tXpSZ4pDm4Jqcke@grONfWlJQWuKWX5Qbq1YHNqXO8j8A)

Returns a \$(N\times N)\times(N\times N)\$ array.

```
  Array[    ,#+0{,,,}]          N x N x N x N array, where values are
#^                                N^
        Plus                        (sum of indices
                      ~Mod~2         mod 2)
```

Comment: The power trick is a nice touch.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>33 23</sup> 19 bytes

```
]^2|i.+/2|+/^:2~@i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYyxCsIwGIT3PsXRJUhtKtGpUhCFTuLgbiHUPyaijSRREIqvHmu7Odxw993dNaacKVQlGOZYoByUc@yO@zqeGtEbnhWiz4qmFJ@N4XGWHLYctXV3GYLpLgia4Mg/b8HDW5jAPEh6Qw7BwhP9Gu9xdR5wByXbAC1fI0BrnaMh8Fo@iCdqPK441kUqEmq1xRRBYTl5lufsj6ziFw)

*Note: In TIO I added a formatting function to box each element, which is now a list of digits, to make the correctness more obvious.  If you remove it, the results will still be correct but because of the way J prints by default it won't be immediately clear.*

*-10 thanks to power trick stolen from [att's Wolfram answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241893/15469)*

- `2|...+/^:2~@i.` Creates a 0-1 checkerboard in the n x n x n dimensions of the input
- `i.+` Creates n versions of that, adding 0, 1, ... n elementwise.
- `]^` Raises input to those 0-1 matrices, creating matrices of 1 and n.  This is really the end of the golf.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 16 bytes

```
₀Ẏ:v꘍:£vv‡¥꘍?‹*›
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigoDhuo46duqYjTrCo3Z24oChwqXqmI0/4oC5KuKAuiIsIiIsIjQiXQ==)

A huge mess.

Comment: This was one of my first thoughts too but I don't think it qualifies.  Try it with 4, for example.

Comment: @Jonah Oops. (filler)

Comment: @Jonah Fixed. (filler)

Comment: According to [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/241888/supersquares-nxn/241892?noredirect=1#comment545173_241888), you may still need some additional separation rather than the single block?  Though tbh I am not entirely sure...

Comment: Looks correct now.

Answer (score 3):

## [GeoGebra](https://geogebra.org/), 92 bytes

```
n=2
a=Zip(Zip(Mod(b-a,2),b,1…n),a,1…n)
b=(n-1)a+1
l=Zip(Zip(b+Mod(d,2)(n+1-2b),d,c),c,a)
```

[Try It On GeoGebra!](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/qqnk4cqu)

`n` is the input, and `l` is the output.

The output is in the form of an array of depth 4:

- Inside the outermost list (layer 1) is the rows of the supersquare (layer 2)
- Inside the second layer is each individual matrix in the supersquare (layer 3)
- Insde the third layer is each row of a particular matrix entry in the supersquare (layer 4)

The default input is `n=2`, but you can change this to whatever input you want.

Output for `n=2` (layers labelled):

```
{{{{1, 2}, {2, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {1, 2}}}, {{{2, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 1}}}}
||||__4_|        |                  |                                      |
|||______3_______|                  |                                      |
||_______________2__________________|                                      |
|____________________________________1_____________________________________|
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 48 bytes

```
n->matrix(n,,i,j,matrix(n,,k,l,n^((i+j+k+l)%2)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcpBCoAgEEDRqwxBMIPjomirRwncGKM2ibjo9larNh8e/Bqa2KOOCG6o9WfoTW5UZuHEvzIX1h1RTDLZFJpXIhrxaqjgYGHYGGoT7a8nsP5NRP2eBw)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
L4ãOÉmIFIô
```

The modulo-2 exponent trick is taken from [*@att*'s Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241893/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx@TwYv/Dnbmebp6Ht/yvteVS4gooSi0pqdQtKMrMK0lNUcgvLSkoLbFSUNLxOj0HqOjwhsN7gdSjpjWHdh/aZnR4@uG99v9NAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/qquSZV1BaYqWgZO93eMKhlTpcSo7JJaWJOQr5pSVQif8@JocX@x/uzD20zu3QusNb/tfacikFFKWWlFTqFhRl5pWkpiBU63idngNSdHjD4b0g@lHTmkO7D20zOjz98F6dQ9vs/wMA).

**Explanation:**

```python
L           # Push a list in the range [1,(implicit) input]
 4ã         # Create all possible quartets of these values,
            # by using the cartesian power of 4
   O        # Sum each inner list
    É       # Check for each sum whether it's odd
     m      # Take the (implicit) input to the power of these 0s/1s,
            # so all 0s become 1 and all 1s become the input-digit
      IF    # Loop the input amount of times:
        Iô  #  Split the list into an input amount of parts
            # (after which the multi-dimensional matrix is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>114</s></sup> 111 bytes

```c
k;j;i;f(n){for(i=0;n*n/++i;puts(i%n?"":"\n"))for(j=0;n/++j;putchar(32))for(k=0;n/++k;)printf("%d",i+j+k&1?:n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/BDoIwDIbvPEWzBLM5iCA3KuFFvJAhONBKAKMJ4dWdmxDsae33/WmnwlopY1psUGPFSUzVo@c6i5D2dJBSY/ccB659yhlL2ZmYEM5onGF547i6Fj1PjgtpV9Ki6HpNY8WZX7JAy0a2uzhPSeBs7BzuhSYuYPLAlk0Cd1NN5eUNGUS4Pk@QINhDXCN@7pJw5QJk5cWUEOOG/rshBXt2AHbxRt1Pl272ZvNR1a2oBxO@vg)

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!*

Answer (score 1):

## **Python 3, 181 bytes**

```python
def s(n):
    a=f'1{n}'*n
    b,c=' '.join(([a[:n],a[1:n+1]]*n)[:n]),' '.join(([a[1:n+1],a[:n]]*n)[:n])
    return '\n\n'.join((['\n'.join(([b,c]*n)[:n]),'\n'.join(([c,b]*n)[:n])]*n)[:n])
```

1. Creates a single row for a single box
2. Makes a complete row (N rows) of alternating boxes
3. Return a string containing N rows of N-rows boxes

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 111 bytes

```powershell
param($a)($s=1..($a*$a))|%{$b++
-join($s|%{"1$a"[($_+$b)%2]
.($g={if(!($_%$a)){$args;$b+=1-$a%2}})' '})
.$g ''}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtNDsIgEEb3cwokg4ANTUB3hpMYY6hpa5tqG7pwgZwdR5Pu3vt@lvndxvXRTpO5z7Et2PlUlhDDU2HQCldv65rwQKY/ImFTVWDGeXhRR84tBn5ReKuw0cJdgca9T0OndhSK3ythiP16pqe3BoNwOWvJZNZQY8@kzCUD7LFjFjj/g9vguMEJyhc)

-2 bytes thanks to [mazzy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80745/mazzy)!
-9 bytes thanks to [mazzy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80745/mazzy) again!

Comment: nice. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYqxDsIgFEX39xW1eRgQaQK68iXGGGog1lRpYHBAvh2fQwfdzrnnLvHlU775eVbXmHzDYEtbXHIPjk7oYeCYLbodyZsVdY/Tk9OKmYweey1OHC8SR8HMGabAN6SM3qL0XQ84SqsVOmZqFX/5pxLK2irAFkOngeIXzAqHFY7QPg "PowerShell Core – Try It Online") ?

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtNDsIgEEb3cwokg4ANTUB3hpMYY6hpa5tqG7pwgZwdR5Pu3vt@lvndxvXRTpO5z7Et2PlUlhDDU2HQCldv65rwQKY/ImFTVWDGeXhRR84tBn5ReKuw0cJdgca9T0OndhSK3ythiP16pqe3BoNwOWvJZNZQY8@kzCUD7LFjFjj/g9vguMEJyhc "PowerShell Core – Try It Online") ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
ＮθＥθＥθ⪫Ｅθ⭆θ∨¬﹪⁺⁺⁺ιλνπ²θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oroCgzr0TDN7FAo1BHAUp55WfmwYSCS4AK0qEc/yINv3yg6vyU0px8jYCc0mIkIlNHIUdTRyEPiAuA2EgTSBRqgkglBSUgrWn9/7/Jf92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ                          Input `n` as an integer
   θ                        Input `n`
  Ｅ                         Map over implicit range
     θ                      Input `n`
    Ｅ                       Map over implicit range
        θ                   Input `n`
       Ｅ                    Map over implicit range
          θ                 Input `n`
         ⭆                  Map over implicit range and join
               ⁺⁺⁺ιλνπ       Sum of all indices
             ¬﹪       ²      Is divisible by `2`
           ∨                Logical Or
                      θ     Input `n`
      ⪫                     Join with spaces
                            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 56 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,w=4,y)=>w?[...Array(n)].map(_=>f(n,w-1,y=!y)):y?n:1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3NCoJAFIX3PsVtNxd0QGqlXKXnqMjBNBS7I@OoDNGzT9oPbVqd78D5adWkhtI0vY1YXyrvaxIczrQLHVI25wcp5d4Y5QTjSd5UL86U1WskikNHG4eYuJyT2Ncjl7bRDHq0/WiXPNwDgEkZsECwdDBdfKl50F0lO30V9jVoKfsHrW64KPCt8IUj/2jl4BF8/raY@ic)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 89 bytes

```
f=lambda n,s=" \n\n",p=0:s.join(j[s>"":]or f(n,s[:-1],j>"1")for j in(n*str(10+n))[p:n+p])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3I9NscxJzk1ISFfJ0im2VFGLyYvKUdApsDayK9bLyM_M0sqKL7ZSUrGLzixTSNIBqoq10DWN1suyUDJU004CCWQpARXlaxSVFGoYG2nmamtEFVnnaBbGaUAuMC4oy80o00jQMNTW5IGwYnaZhjEXMRBOqFeZGAA)

Returns a single string. Most lines have a trailing space.

Answer (score 1):

## [Labra](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Labra), 69 bytes

```
()[]([])
()[<><{}>]<[{}<[]>]>
<[]><<>>[](<>[])<<>>
{}(())<<><<>><<>>>
```

I've been waiting for a month and a half for a question Labra could actually compete in.

Prints as a list: [[[[1, 2], [2, 1]], [[2, 1], etc...

```
For input = 3 (Which Labra receives as [3])
()[]([])                    [1,0]
()[<><{}>]                  Starting at n=1, n=[1,0][n]: [1,0,1,0,1,...]
          <[{}<[]>]>        Index with [1...input[1]]:   [0,1,0]
<[]><<>>                    Index into first line:       [1,0,1]
        [](<>[])            Put in list and add [0,1,0]: [[1,0,1],[0,1,0]]
                <<>>        Index with [0,1,0]:          [[1,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]
{}(())                      Input (already a list) + 1:  [3,1]
      <          >          Index that with
       <>                   previous line:       [[1,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]
         <<>>               indexed with itself: [[[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,0]],[[1,0,1],[0,1,0],...
             <<>>           twice:               [[[[1,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,1]],[[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,0]],...
                            giving:                      [[[[1,3,1],[3,1,3],[1,3,1]],[[3,1,3],[1,3,1],[3,1,3]],...
                            (implicit output)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 129 bytes

```php
for(;$a++<$n=$argn;){for($b=0;$b++<$n;){for($c=0;$c++<$n;){for($d=0;$d++<$n;)echo($a+$b+$c+$d)%2?$n:1;echo" ";}echo"
";}echo"
";}
```

I feel like there's probably a way that this could be done better with a recursive function, but I can't wrap my head around it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVErW1bVTybFUSi9LzrDWrQYIqSbYG1ipJYAmYUDJIKBlFKAUklAIVSk3OyNcAGgbUBlSmkqKpamSvkmdlaA2SUFJQsq4FM7iQGf//m/zLLyjJzM8r/q/rBgA)